# How to get with SharePoint client APIs all user profiles?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

For implementing a birthday's SharePoint 2013 app I need to get all user profiles from a site collection. For this purpose I'd like to use a (or multiple) client API(s). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163800.aspx#bkmk_APIversions.

Unfortunately I couldn't find in the APIs description an equivalent of `Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles`. There are in `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PeopleManager` two methods, `GetUserProfilePropertiesFor` and `GetUserProfilePropertyFor`, that only get a single user profile.

So my question is: how to get with CSOM, JSOM, REST (or any client side technology) all user profiles in site collection?

Answer (score 4):

Since CSOM provides methods for operations related to people **per user** scope, you could retrieve all site users first using [SP.Web.siteUsers property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245773.aspx). and then use 
[SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager.getUserProfilePropertyFor Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj667887.aspx) to get `BirthDay` property as demonstrated below:

```
//Get Birthday User Profile Property for Site Users 
function getUsersBirthdays(Success,Error) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = clientContext.get_web(); 

    var users = web.get_siteUsers();
    clientContext.load(users);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    function() {
       var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);
       var personsProperties = [];
       for(var i = 0; i < users.get_count();i++)
       {
           var user = users.getItemAtIndex(i);
           var personBirthday = peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertyFor(user.get_loginName(),'SPS-Birthday');
           personsProperties.push(personBirthday);
       }

       clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
           function() {
             Success(personsProperties);
           },
           Error);

    },
    Error);



}



//Usage
var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_layouts/15/';
$.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.js', function () {
  $.getScript(scriptbase + 'SP.UserProfiles.js', function () {
    getUsersBirthdays(function(usersProperties){
       for(var i = 0; i < usersProperties.length;i++)
       {
           console.log(usersProperties[i].get_value());
       }
    },
    function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Vadim Gremyachev for your answer. For performance reasons I eventually solved it with a REST search query:

`var queryUrl = appweburl + "/_api/search/query?"
    + "querytext='*'"
    + "&sourceid='B09A7990-05EA-4AF9-81EF-EDFAB16C4E31'"
    + "&rowlimit=500"
    + "&selectproperties='PreferredName,Birthday'";

    $.ajax({
        url: queryUrl,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: successHandler,
        error: errorHandler
    });`

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/22/get-all-users-and-groups-client-object-model-sharepoint-2010/) also should work for SP2013

```
function GetUsersGroups(){

  ClientContext context = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("http://SPSite");

  GroupCollection groupCollection = context.Web.SiteGroups;
  context.Load(groupCollection,
  groups = > groups.Include(group = > group.Users));

  context.ExecuteQuery();

  foreach (Group group in groupCollection)
  {
    UserCollection userCollection = group.Users;

    foreach (User user in userCollection)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("User Name: " + user.Title + " Email: " + user.Email + " Login: " + user.LoginName);
    }
  }
  //Iterate the owners group
  Group ownerGroup = context.Web.AssociatedOwnerGroup;
  context.Load(ownerGroup);
  context.Load(ownerGroup.Users);
  context.ExecuteQuery();
  foreach (User ownerUser in ownerGroup.Users)
  {
    MessageBox.Show("User Name: " + ownerUser.Title + " Email: " + ownerUser.Email + " Login: " + ownerUser.LoginName);
  }
  context.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Greg, but that works for `Users` not for `User Profiles`. I need to pick up the date of birth.

Comment: Hi @Greg, `SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser` is equivalent to `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.PeopleManager.GetUserProfilePropertiesFor`. To get all user profiles you should first retrieve all users and then retrieve the corresponding profile for each user. That's not really performance friendly. I just want to give up a few filters at once and only get back the results that meet these criteria.